# Trying to get a UWP app to recognise custom HID descriptor

Tags: uwp, hid, windows-10-iot-core

I am attempting to get a custom HID device (currently running on a raspberry pi zero) to be recognised by a UWP app running on Windows 10. The device is of type Vendor Defined so doesn't fall in the list of devices blocked on UWP (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice)

I have written a report descriptor and it is currently being picked up by the Device Manager in Windows. In Device Manager under Properties > Details > Hardware IDs the VID and PID are displayed. There is no HID_Device_UP though as I have seen in tutorials (http://www.idevstream.com/?p=322).

My descriptor is as follows:

```
06 AA ff            USAGE_PAGE (Vendor Defined Page 1)
09 01       USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
A1 01       COLLECTION (Application)
15 00       LOGICAL MINIMUM (0)
26 ff 00        LOGICAL MAXIMUM (255)
75 08       REPORT SIZE (8)
95 40       REPORT COUNT (64)
09 01       USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
81 00       INPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
09 01       USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
91 00       OUTPUT (Data,Ary,Abs)
c0          END COLLECTION
```

In a bash script on the Raspberry Pi that runs at boot I am setting the following as the VID and PID:

```
echo 0x45E > idVendor
echo 0x610 > idProduct
```

This is the code used to try and access the HID device:

```
private async void EnumerateHidDevices()
{
    ushort vendorId = 0x045E;
    ushort productId = 0x0610;
    ushort usagePage = 0xFFAA;
    ushort usageId = 0x01;

    string selector =
            HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vendorId, productId);        

    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

    if (devices.Any())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("HID devices found: " + devices.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("HID device not found");
    }
}
```

In the Package.appxmanifest I have included the following:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
    <Device Id="vidpid:045E 0610">
      <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific" />
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>

<DeviceCapability Name="usb"> 
    <Device Id="vidpid:045E 0610">
        <Function Type="classId:ff * *"/>
        <!--<Function Type="name:vendorSpecific"/>-->
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the link, the order for the usage is important here. The Function Type element specifies the device function. This element contains one or more HID usage values. These values consist of a Usage Page and an optional Usage Id, each of which are 16-bit hexadecimal values. You may try with following content in Package.appxmanifest.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
    <Device Id="vidpid:045E 0610">
      <Function Type="usage:FFAA 0001"/>
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

**or**

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
    <Device Id="any">
      <Function Type="usage:FFAA *"/>
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

More details please see this document([How to specify device capabilities for HID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-hid)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried both configurations as well as specifying USB but still no luck detecting the device.

Comment: Did you use `devcon.exe` to  identify the installed HID device and driver?